# New column in pandas dataframe from dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [111, 333, 456]})
```

And I have a dictionary with keys that correspond to a category and values with the type list.

```
dct = {'A': [111, 222, 333, 444], 'B': [123, 456, 789]}
```

The values in the list may or may not be found in `col1`. I'd like to create `col2` that would return the key from `dct`.

My desired output is this:

```
col1   |   col2
-------+---------
111    |    A
333    |    A
456    |    B
```

I've tried `df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(dct)` but this returns `NaN` values.

Comment: Is it possible that the value of col1 is in both the lists associated with 'A' and 'B' in dct? Or is there always only at most one match

Comment: the contents of the dict are `A` and `B`, the contents of df_col1 are numbers, the code is working as intended since it seems the problem is that your trying to go backwards

Comment: @Tim J No, the lists are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: [key for key in dct if x in dct[key]][0])
```

Returning:

```
   col1 col2
0   111    A
1   333    A
2   456    B
```